How can I transfer or copy AWS EC2 snapshots to GCP?
I need to transfer or copy 119 ec2 snapshots that are in aws to gcp, can anyone help me?
I contacted gcp support but received documentation that did not help me.
https://cloud.google.com/migrate/compute-engine/docs/4.8/how-to/migrate-aws-to-gcp/migrating-aws-vms
https://cloud.google.com/migrate/compute-engine/docs/4.8/how-to/organizing-migrations/overview
I have explored other Google documentation in addition to those provided by support but have not been successful.
